# How to apply CSS rule to header-and-paragraphs by pseudo classes/elements?

Tags: html, css

How can I apply a CSS rule to groups of header-and-multiple-paragraphs, based on pattern/position?

See that the below text contains three sets of `<h3>`s and multiple `<p>`s beneath them. Let's regard them all as article segments by, say, wrapping a border around each group.

How can this be achieved without actually applying `class="classname"` or adding new `<div>`s anywhere? Ie. Can it be inferred, achieved by using positioning, maybe nth items/preceding-type stuff?

I note that CSS pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements may be what is relevant here.

Qualifying attributes:

- Where there is a `<h3>`
- ... followed by multiple `<p>`s (unpredictable number)
- ... until (but not including) the *next* header...
- ... or until the end
- ... (ie. up to the last `<p>` before some different element - may not always be a header tag)
- ... wrap it in a `border: 1px` box.

```
<h3>Cross-heading 1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum lectus ac justo dapibus dapibus.</p>
<p>Maecenas ipsum quam, tincidunt sed condimentum quis, pharetra eget lorem. Praesent ultrices non nisi sit amet iaculis.</p>
<p>Maecenas ultricies ipsum enim, lobortis pharetra metus scelerisque eu. Nulla lacus dolor, venenatis quis interdum quis, euismod vel turpis.</p>
<h3>Cross-heading 2</h3>
<p>Aenean mi elit, elementum ut diam sed, maximus euismod neque. Nulla convallis malesuada eleifend.</p>
<p>Nulla efficitur rhoncus orci, cursus vestibulum urna volutpat a. Etiam molestie ligula non leo pulvinar, a vulputate arcu maximus.</p>
Nullam faucibus sollicitudin sapien sit amet aliquam. Aliquam scelerisque, nisl sit amet convallis tempor, ante mauris lacinia arcu, sit amet rutrum nulla ante at tortor.</p>
<p>Etiam sed turpis in nunc sodales molestie ac vestibulum nulla. Suspendisse hendrerit in dolor a porttitor.</p>
<p>Aenean eget bibendum diam. Nam pulvinar enim eu lacus aliquam auctor. Fusce nec posuere elit, ac ultricies nisl. Ut lacinia vitae est sed sodales.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<h3>Cross-heading 3</h3>
<p>Sed posuere justo nec ex maximus, sit amet lacinia nisl finibus.</p>
<p>Curabitur nec mauris a velit pellentesque commodo eget quis ipsum.</p>
<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nam auctor quam malesuada pretium feugiat.</p>
<p>Fusce vel purus posuere, ultrices urna et, elementum augue. Pellentesque nec auctor dolor.</p>
<p>Nunc eget consectetur diam. Suspendisse quam urna, posuere nec libero id, bibendum dapibus est. Phasellus nulla ex, facilisis eu mi non, varius eleifend enim.</p>
```

Comment: Generally I would say no as, I suspect at some point you are going to need a "previous sibling selector! " which does not exist. With your example it IS possible but I would suggest that this is extremely fragile - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJzybjd?editors=1100

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. Oh, I see what you're doing. Yeah, it doesn't currently put a left or right on a non-<p> element. 1) Could we extend border-left and border-right to all conceivable tags/any element? Let's say the whole thing was wrapped in <article>, does that give more leeway? And 2) I note :last-child doesn't seem to properly accommodate the idea of "whatever the final element might be".

Comment: As I said, I really suspect that this is not something you should be doing with CSS as I think your selectors are going to be too generic or outright impossible.

Comment: Frankly, re-jigging the HTML into a proper structure would be your best option here.

Comment: Yeah, tricky as CMSes are typically configured with articles stored in one big 'ol dumb textarea. I think I'd have to think about building a segmented article builder (single article stored as multiple fields) to add classes where necessary, which I'm interested in doing, but thought I'd first check whether that would be over-engineering, whether CSS could just do it.

Comment: You can do it for your example code with a combo of pseudo elements and borders as you can select p elements that come immediately after an h3 and so on, but it is, as @Paulie_D says fragile unless you are absolutely certain no other element could creep in.